# Selecting Parent and Child List into a view model using LINQ or Fluent

Tags: linq, parent-child, fluent

Can anyone give me some advice on how I can use LINQ to populate my view model in one query/command...

Basically, I have a view model which is something like follows:

```
public class ReportViewModel
{
     public string ReportName {get; set;}

     public List<Section> Sections {get; set;}
}
```

My models are something along the lines of

```
public class Report
{
     public int ReportId {get; set;}
     public string ReportName {get; set;}
     public virtual ICollection<Section> sections {get; set;}
}

public class Section
{
     public int SectionId {get; set;}
     public int ReportId {get; set;}
     public string SectionName {get; set;}
     public string SectionData {get; set;}
}
```

And what I want to do is create a link query that will populate a list of all report names and their sections+data.... something along the lines of

```
List<ReportViewModel> rvm = await _context.Report.SelectMany(r => r.SectionData).ToListAsync();
```

or

```
List<ReportViewModel> sections = await
(
     from r in _context.Reports
     from s in r.Sections
     select new ReportViewModel() { ReportName = r.ReportName, Sections = s}
).ToListAsync();
```

but I can't get either of these to work...

Can anyone offer me some advice or point me in the direction of an answer?

(Also, thats not actually my view model or model but should hopefully give an idea of what i'm trying to achieve).

Cheers,

Dan

Comment: At what point does `Report` have a property for `Sections` or `SectionData` ?

Comment: Sorry Mark... Report should have a virtual property which is of type ICollection<Section>. I'll add it to the example (I've written that from scratch to strip out all the toot to make it easier to read).

Comment: What does the second linq query return? The `from r in _context.Reports......`  query

Comment: It gives an error saying can not implicitly convert a type of Section into a List<Section>.

Comment: It seems like the navigation property to Sections is not configured correctly. Do you have it set up as a 1:M relationship? Based on `public virtual ICollection<Section> sections {get; set;}` it looks like it should be a collection and should be bringing back a list of Sections.

Comment: Hi Mark, it seems to be set up correctly as it works for everything else. For example, if I select a report and do .Include(r => r.Sections) then the Sections list is populated with the correct Sections...

Comment: Have you tried that route (using `Include`) ? `await _context.Report.Include(r => r.sections).Select(rs => //to view model here).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

Mark C has answered my question for me. Mark, if you want to repost your last comment I'll mark it as an answer! Thank you!

Basically, the code I used was something along the lines of:

```
List<ReportViewModel> rvm = await _context.Report
    .Include(r => r.sections)
    .Select(r => new ReportViewModel() 
    {
        ReportName = r.ReportName, 
        Sections = r.sections
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```